# [R]cholmod_l_dense_to_sparse failure status=-4

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I was trying to convert dgeMatrix to dgCMatrix but got this error:

```
> temp<-as(IMatrix,"dgCMatrix")
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  dense_to_Csparse(<LARGE>): cholmod_l_dense_to_sparse failure status=-4
```

My dgeMatrix has this information:

```
> str(IMatrix)
Formal class 'dgeMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 4 slots
  ..@ x       : num [1:2515323860] 0 0 0 0.0521 0.186 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 24919 100940
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:100940] "5891STDY8642957#TGACAACGTTAGGAAT-1" "5891STDY8642957#CACGTTCTCGATGAAA-1" "5891STDY8642957#CAAGAAATCTACCCGT-1" "5891STDY8642957#GGGCCATTCGATAGCT-1" ...
  ..@ factors : list()
```

I googled around and couldn't find a solution.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.3-4/topics/dgeMatrix-class) a `dgeMatrix` is  "a general **dense** numeric matrix" (emphasis added). I don't think `Matrix` necessarily supports sparse non-numeric matrices ... ?  How did you construct `Imatrix` in the first place ...?

Comment: Are you 100% sure there isn't an inf or an nan buried somewhere in your data? `-4` is invalid input, which usually means something like that. (I don't know what the other comments are on about - you have a perfectly normal dense matrix and it should convert to Csparse no problem)

Comment: Do you know how to check that? @CJR

Comment: I did this:
`sum(!is.finite(IMatrix))`
The output is this` [1] 0`

Comment: I dunno - try calling `Matrix(IMatrix, sparse=T)` instead, that constructor might work or throw a more useful error.